# Images packing algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, packing

I would like to create a list of images packed the same way Facebook is doing when you look at an album:

[image: Facebook packed tiles]

So, the input data is:

1. we have a `infinite` list of images with known `width` and `height`
2. we have a `container` with a known `width` and infinite height
3. we want to show the images in the order they are listed on a prefered number of columns, adjusting their widths to fit in the container width
4. sometimes the images are covering one or two or multiple rows as wel portrait or landscape

Some ascii scene covering the possible situations:

```
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|                  |                  |                  |
|   Normal tile    |    Normal tile   |    Normal tile   |
|                  |                  |                  |
|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|                                     |                  |
|        Landscape tile               |                  |
|                                     |                  |
|------------|------------------------|------------------|
|            |                        |                  |
| Smaller    |  Landscape tile        |    Normal tile   |
|            |                        |                  |
|------------|--|------------------|--|------------------|
|               |                  |                     |
| Portrait tile |    Normal tile   |    Larger tile      |
|               |                  |                     |
|               |------------------|---------------------|
|               |                     |                  |
|               |    Larger tile      |    Normal tile   |
|               |                     |                  |
|---------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I thought about using Treemap algorithm from D3 js but I am not quite sure if that would be the right choice given that in my problem I don't know the height of the container.

[Treemap](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582)

It is a packing problem.

Any help or idea will be appreciated!

**Update**

It is acceptable that images to be scaled or clipped to better fit the layout.
So, for example, if there is place for a square tile to fill a row and the current image is a portrait one, the algorithm may scale the image to the available width and clip it to the available height, or the other way around.

Comment: You might want to check out the Flexbox grid system. https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Comment: A treemap is not the best choice here. The hole point of a treemap is generating the rectangles dynamically, according to the passed value and the tiling method. That's clearly not what you want, since you have predefined width and height for each element.

Comment: Thanks @NicoVanBelle that looks like a good resource!

Comment: The *whole* point, not the *hole* point, sorry (S.O. should really increase the 5 minute grace period for editing comments).

Comment: The question is, how these multiline tiles appear? In the task set there is no condition that makes us to create a thingie such as your Portrait Tile. I think, you should define some limits or weights to make the SW to create wider or higher tiles. For example, to set some medium area - 10000pix. And every tile can have area in the interval 5000 till 20000 pix. Then sometimes you must create landscape or portrait tiles, because you have long-rectangle images.

Comment: BTW, you obviously mix the width and the height. Width of the while field is horizontal, and width of a stripe is vertical? Put terms more consistantly.

Comment: Is the height of the strip fixed?

Comment: @Gangnus, the images appear at once. The `row` height is not fixed but might be an acceptable restriction if the algorithm is simplified significantly by that. 

I am not mixing the widths and heights. The only thing that is fixed and known is the parent container width and the desired number of `"columns"` which occasionally might get  `colspanned` or `rowspaned`, in a table-like acceptance.

Comment: If the horisontal size of the tiles is very unstable, I would not speak about columns. I think, that trying to think of them, you are crating problems for yourself.

Comment: @Gangnus, it was more of a figure of speech. There are no actual columns. There are flexible tiles where summed widths of horizontal neighbours tiles fits the container, and when a tile is higher than the others its height will match up the heights sum of its neighbours . As it shows my "ascii art" above :)

Answer (score 0):

Set minimal acceptable area of the tile and standard height of the row.

1. Show images by one, adapting the tile so that its height is equal to the row height. If you have no place for the next tile, we can expand all finished row so that its width will be the max width and go to the next row. We can go on also without expanding, for it seems impossible with portraits. Notice, that landscape tiles are not the special case.
2. Low Row. If the image is too low and wide to fit in the row height and width, make a low row of one tile, adapting tile's width to the row width. ( you have forgotten about that case, that makes showing images ALWAYS in order simply impossible without appearance of half-empty rows)  You should put that image after the last filled row with even lower border (without extending portraits). If there is not such row, add to the start. So, you have to remember the last place where you add normal pictures and the last place where you can add low rows.
   2.1. Another possible place for a low row is a last shortened row with the same width as the next shortened row. (look for Portraits)
3. If the tile after adjustment has area smaller than minimally acceptable, you will create a Portrait.
   3.1. According to the minimal area we count the iheight of the portrait - measured in rows. Also, its height and width.
   3.2. As we can not really keep up to the source order, we'll put the portrait to the left. Several next rows, including this one, will be shortened.
   3.3. If there are several portraits, starting or continuing on that row, they should be ordered, according to their lower border, from the lowest to the highest. But anyway, if we have the previous row started by 2-high portrait, and we have another one such portrait now, there will be a gap in the next row.
   3.4. If we have a gap, we remember it, and when in future, we have a normal picture or a fitting portrait, we insert it in the gap. The gaps won't be complex, look the next point.
   3.5. If the large number of portraits is possible (better think it IS possible), check the future images for possible portraits, and if you have more than 1 for two rows, increase the current standard row height. Also, of course, move all found portraits to that higher row. After that you drop the standard row height back.

Comment: If you check to see how Facebook displays pictures of an album you will see there is no gap. My guess is that having the ability of deciding in what proportion and how much of an image will be clipped will solve the gaping issue.

Comment: The gap appears on some stage of creation, not at the final result. BTW, where have you got the info, that Facebook shows pictures this or that way on ANY combination of wide or high pictures? Have you tested their algorithm? The example you are showing is absolute primitive - almost all pictures are about squares.